# Could not able to get the text of elements. I want to use the dynamic xpath here to get the text of the header elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML. I want to use the dynamic xpath here to get the text of the header elements.

```html
<div class="w3-bar w3-theme w3-card-2 w3-wide notranslate">
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white w3-padding-16 hidesm" onclick="w3_open()" href="javascript:void(0)">
<a id="navbtn_tutorials" class="w3-bar-item w3-button barex w3-hover-white w3-padding-16" onclick="w3_open_nav('tutorials')" href="javascript:void(0)">
TUTORIALS
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
<i class="fa fa-caret-up" style="display:none"></i>
</a>
```

```
hElements = "//div[@class='w3-bar w3-theme w3-card-2 w3-wide notranslate']//a" 
#is my xpath fetches all the header elements
hElementsSize = len(browser.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(hElements)) 
#fetches the size of the header elements
print("Total Header Elements:", hElementsSize)
hElementsText = browser.driver.find_element_by_xpath(hElements).text
print(hElementsText) 
#i'm not able to get the text of the header elements
```

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. Right now the html you provided is incomplete edit it and format it like html

Answer (score 0):

The way you are expecting text using `browser.driver.find_element_by_xpath` will return first element's text which is empty as i can see in HTML shared by You. `findElement` locates the first element in the DOM in case multiple elements are there.

Need to use `find_elements` and loop through to check expected one

```
hElements = "//div[@class='w3-bar w3-theme w3-card-2 w3-wide notranslate']//a"
listOfElement = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(hElements)
print("Total Header Elements:", len(listOfElement))

for element in listOfElement:
    print(element.text)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I could only fetch text of 4/8(out of 1 is empty element) other 3 elements are like icons/images. But on mouse hover the title of the icon displays. Here is the HTML for the other 3 elements(icons). <div class="w3-right">
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white w3-padding-16 w3-right" title="Search W3Schools" onclick="open_search(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">
<i class="fa"></i>
</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return them all, assuming your xpath is correct, you would have to use find_element**s**_by_xpath. Then it returns a list of all the elements it found.

```
hElementsText = browser.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(hElements)
for el in hElementsText:
    print(el.text)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I could only fetch text of 4/8(out of 1 is empty element) other 3 elements are like icons/images. But on mouse hover the title of the icon displays. Here is the HTML for the other 3 elements(icons). <div class="w3-right">
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white w3-padding-16 w3-right" title="Search W3Schools" onclick="open_search(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">
<i class="fa"></i>
</a>

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to retrieve the text from the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()` method:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.w3-bar.w3-theme.w3-card-2.w3-wide.notranslate a#navbtn_tutorials"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='w3-bar w3-theme w3-card-2 w3-wide notranslate']//a[@id='navbtn_tutorials']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```